# Creating Php pages for multiple user types

Tags: php, html

I need to create a website where different user can login and for each type user, they will have same and also different buttons. I have a homepage(for a visitor of if a user has not logged in, an admin homepage for admin login with different features or buttons, a student homepage for student login with different buttons or features.

Login code

```
<?php
include('../database.php');
$email = '';
$password = '';
$login_type = '';

if (isset($_GET['type']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $login_type = $_GET['type'];
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = ? AND type= ?;";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $email, $login_type);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

$current_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if (!password_verify($password, $current_user['password'])) {
    //Wrong credentials   
    header("Location: ../LoginPage.php?error=401&type=$login_type");
} else {
    //Login successful. Creates session of the user.
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['firstname'] = $current_user['firstname'];
    $_SESSION['lastname'] = $current_user['lastname'];
    $_SESSION['logintype'] = $current_user['type'];

    if ($current_user['type'] == 'admin') {
        header('Location: ../AdminHome.php?usertype="admin"');
    } else if ($current_user['type'] == 'student') {
        header('Location: ../StudentHome.php?usertype="student"');
    } else {
        die('404: File not Found!');
    }
}
```

homepage for visitor is just plain html code

homepage for admin login

```
<?php
include('database.php');
$usertype= "";

    session_start();
if ($_SESSION['firstname'] && $_SESSION['lastname']) {
  $firstname = $_SESSION['firstname'];
  $lastname = $_SESSION['lastname'];
  
} else {
  header('Location: LibraryHome.php?login=false');
}
?>
```

This is also the same for the student homepage

now my problem is they have same buttons like

home button browse button login button

and they have the different buttons on their top nav

```
                         visitorbuttons   visitorbuttons
```

homebutton

browse button

login button

```
                      adminbuttons   adminbuttons
```

homebutton

browse button

login button

```
                      studentbuttons  studentbuttons
```

homebutton

browse button

login button

I want to create the pages in a way that i will not need to create many pages whenever i click buttons for different users type

for example, if i login as admin and clicked browse button, i will see its own top nav, but if i login as student , i will see a different top nav buttons, and for this to do, i need to create a browse page for each of different user type.this is also the case for login and home button.

Is there any way to do this optimally without creating too many pages?

Comment: Certainly.  You store the usertype in the user table.  When a user logs in you use their type to render the appropriate menus and buttons.  Individual functions that are only possible for a specific type of user should have a security check that prevents access to any feature that is not relevant for a specific user type.  Dont do this:  `header('Location: ../AdminHome.php?usertype="admin"');`  that is no security.  Anyone looking at the responses from your website can see what you are doing and do it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use the $_SESSION['logintype'] to define what content to show by having buttons wrapped in conditions like:

```
<?php
    if ($_SESSION['logintype'] === 'admin') {
        echo "Element that can only be seen by admins";
    }
?>
```

You then only need one page but you can define different headers, navbars, buttons, anything you like depending on the user type.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Sir is there any way to detect if a user has a logged in or if a session is active? I tried putting my code in a page if a user has not logged in but it gives me error '    session_start();
if ($_SESSION['firstname'] && $_SESSION['lastname']) {
  $firstname = $_SESSION['firstname'];
  $lastname = $_SESSION['lastname'];
  
} '

Comment: Yes actually!
You can do that by checking for the existence of the value before checking for the value itself:`if (isset($_SESSION['logintype'])) //true if connected, false if not`
Trying to use $_SESSION['logintype'] if it is not set will result, as you saw, in an error.

Comment: Doing isset() is the old school way.  Use `if (empty($_SESSION['logintype'])) then { ..redirect to login page. exit() }` now.  That would be a simple security check.

Comment: I put if (isset($_SESSION['logintype'])) before verifying user type and it works really well. Thanks again sir!